# How to read shelf product barcode using OpenCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

I am following this tutorial to read barcode and QR code with OpenCV. The code below works and detect a QR Barcode but I want to use the barcode detector to read barcodes on store products like this [image: like this one]

This code works if the barcode is neatly printed on a white paper or show on a large computer screen.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)


while True:

    success, img = cap.read()
    for barcode in decode(img):
        myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        print(myData)
    
        if myData in myDataList:
            myOutput = 'Authorized'
            myColor = (0,255,0)
        else:
            myOutput = 'Un-Authorized'
            myColor = (0, 0, 255)
    
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon],np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
        cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,myColor,5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        cv2.putText(img,myOutput,(pts2[0],pts2[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.9,myColor,2)

cv2.imshow('Result',img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

How can I fix the code or use other methods to accurately read the barcodes on shelf products ?

Comment: OpenCV has an in-built barcode detector. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you can do what point-of-sale scanners do: scan the product using many differently oriented lines across it, and see if anything in those lines decodes reliably.

barcodes have specific timing constraints (time/distance between edges can't be arbitrary), and they contain checksums. that is how you, or zbar, can discard scanlines that run across an object in arbitrary locations. you don't have to know where the barcode is.

you would sample the image across various lines and feed these samples to zbar's low level interface, which takes a sequence of intensity values per scan.

Comment: Thats actuall what I am trying to build using opencv/tensorflow and cameras